# Удаление option из select по условию

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка с `select`, который содержит список стран. Что-то вроде этого

```
<select name="countries">
<option value="1">Америка</option>
<option value="2">Армения</option>
<option value="3">Бангадеш</option>
...
</select>
```

И там около 100 стран. Подскажите регулярное выражение, которое удалит из строки option по условию так, чтобы например в списке остались только 2 страны - Россия и Зимбабве

Comment: `echo <select name="countries">
<option value="1">Россия</option>
<option value="2">Зимбабве</option></select>`

Comment: @splash58 это понятно. но все же это не ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Мне кажется вы ищеще немного извращеное рещение.

Comment: @koks_rs предположим, в этом select Россия, например, может быть выделана как selected. Т.е. <option selected="" value="14">Россия</option>. А может быть и не выделена. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Почему не ответ? Замени ту строку на эту. Надо сохранить value, найди их и подставь - более понятная задача

Comment: А чтобы совсем правильно, воспльзуйся дом парсером

Answer (score 5, accepted):

само регулярное выражение выглядит следующим образом

```
/<option(.*?)>(?!(Россия|Зимбабве))(.*?)<\/option>/mi
```

Если нужны другие страны, думаю понятно что и где менять.

Теперь разберем более подробно, по пунктам расписав каждую скобку

1. Жадный поиск. Выбирает любой символ до тех пор пока не встретиться `>`
   То есть в `option` можно вставлять любые атрибуты - регулярка их обработает.
2. Внутренняя скобка - в ней простой список через `ИЛИ (|)`
   Внешняя - негативный просмотр вперед. То есть, если регулярке попались то что находится во внутреннем выражении, она ее пропускает. Если нет, то отображает. Так как нам нужно удалить все лишнее, то регулярка выведет нам все кроме этих 2х стран, которые то мы и заменим на `''`.
3. Опять жадный поиск того, что находится внутри.

И в итоге все это дело выглядит как-то так

```
$country = '<select name="countries">
    <option value="1">Америка</option>
    <option value="2">Армения</option>
    <option value="3">Бангадеш</option>
</select>';
$country = preg_replace('/<option(.*?)>(?!(Бангадеш|Армения))(.*?)<\/option>/mi', '', $country);
echo $country;
```