# Рекурсивное регулярное выражение: как задать несовпадение со строкой, а не с отдельными символами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мой php код:

```
      $exp = 'вава<pre>sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>вава';     
      \preg_match_all("#<pre>((?>[^(?:<pre>)(?:</pre>)]|(?R))*)</pre>#si", $exp, $matches);

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($matches as $item) {           
            foreach ($item as $elem)
            {
                echo "$i  ", \htmlentities($elem), "<br>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

На выходе:

> 0 `<pre>sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>`
>
> 1 `sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff`

Это хорошо, так как рекурсивное регулярное выражение работает и находит вложенные теги `<pre>`. Однако проблема тут:

```
[^(?:<pre>)(?:</pre>)]
```

У меня получается описать только класс символов, а не класс, в котором не должно быть строк `<pre>` и `</pre>`. Поэтому если добавить в исходный текст хотя бы символ `p` или `r` все работает не так как надо.

Пример: `$exp = вава<pre>ssspss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>вава; // p среди ssspss`
На выходе

> 0 `<pre>fff</pre>`
>
> 1 `fff`

Скажите, как построить регулярку, чтобы задать несовпадение со строкой, а не с отдельными символами?

---

UPD: Мне дали ответ на [большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604019/recursive-regular-expression-how-to-set-a-mismatch-with-the-string-rather-than/31604672#31604672). Особенно ценным нахожу сайт [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tJ4uE8/1), который подробно расписывает смысл регулярки и тут же ее дает протестировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я конечно не очень понял суть задачи - слишком сумбурное объяснение, но для того чтобы было несовпадение со строкой, или несколькими строками - нужно использовать негативный просмотр вперед

```
(?!(ssspss|fff))
```

Более подробно про несовпадение со строкой я описал в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433242/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-option-%D0%B8%D0%B7-select-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E/433251#433251)